# Styling an elment and class at the same time in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to style a class and a label element the same time, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there a possible way where I can accomplish this with out creating a separate class for in label element, and with out adding a class name to my label element.

Below is my css code

```
 .store_text_color, label {color: #069}
```

Comment: Looks correct, maybe something else have higher priority? Check Developer tools for your browser.

Comment: At least you are missing a `;`there.

Comment: That should work. Could you show us your HTML code that pertains to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the comment, your CSS is fine. The semi-colon is not really necessary.

I'm guessing you have another rule that overrules your style, see the following example on something that have more "priority"

```
body { background-color: red; color: white; }
body label { color: green; }
.store_text_color, label {color: #069}
```

Here's some more information on priority:

- http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Training/Priority_level_of_selector
- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity

Comment: Hey Hank. You where right. There was another label CSS property I didn't see that was overwriting my current label CSS property. I will read upon the link you sent me!